# Changing the color of my Filter button when its being used

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have three separate filters that I am using on a list of items, and have configured them properly so that a popup list of filter categories shows when each button is clicked, I can only use one filter list at a time, and the filters get applied to the list perfectly, rearranging the content to match the filter that is applied.... However, my issue is that my users would like the color of the filter icon to change if it is being used. Here is the XAML style for the buttons:

```
    <Style x:Key="FilterButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="15"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="15"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,0,4,0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Rectangle Name="rectangle" Width="15"    Height="15"   Fill="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}">
                    <Rectangle.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlackBrush" Color="#496161" />
                    </Rectangle.Resources>
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_filter}"/>
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="rectangle" Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have tried the "IsFocused" property in the trigger, but the color changes back once the user selects a filter from the popup list. 
 please let me know if I need to supply any other info or code that would help...

UPDATE: Here is the command that  I am using to apply the filter and clear other filters. I am using the MVVM approach so this is C# in the viewmodel for one of the filter buttons. All three follow this format though, except for the data it returns.

```
    private void ApplyRequestDateFilter(ObservableCollection<CheckBoxListData> filterRequestDateList)
    {
        // List<int> requestAges;
        List<CheckBoxListData> selectedRequestAges;

        ListVM.ToList<AssignListDetailViewModel>().ForEach((p) => p.Cleanup());
        ListVM.Clear();
        PermitList.Clear();

        selectedRequestAges = filterRequestDateList.Where(a => a.IsChecked).ToList();

        if (selectedRequestAges.Count > 0)
        {
            selectedRequestAges.ForEach((x) =>
            {
                PermitList.AddRange((from p in PermitListFromSearch where p.RequestAge >= x.SelectionValuelow && p.RequestAge <= x.SelectionValueHigh select p).ToList());
            });
            PermitList.ForEach((x) => AddToListVM(x));
        }
        else
        {
            PermitListFromSearch.ForEach((x) => AddToListVM(x));
        }

        SetCounters();
        IsRequestDatePopupOpen = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a control that has an IsChecked property like the ToggleButton.  But since only one button can be selected at any time, you should use a RadioButton instead.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,0,4,0" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Rectangle Name="rectangle" Width="15"    Height="15" Fill="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}">
                        <Rectangle.Resources>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlackBrush" Color="#496161" />
                        </Rectangle.Resources>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="rectangle" Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


        <RadioButton IsChecked="False">click me</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton IsChecked="True">click me too</RadioButton>
```

Comment: This does get the button to stay red, but it doesn't change is back to the other color once another filter is selected. the same issue when I use a toggle button. I think the problem surrounds the code that refreshes the view once a new filter is applied. I will update the question above to show that command.

Comment: Since only 1 RadioButton can be checked per 'group', if you check one, the others will automatically become unchecked and change the color back. What you described sounds like your radio buttons inside something else, like a ListBox or some other ItemsControl.  Try the codes on a new window.  You'll see how RadioButtons work.